# Laravel create project issue

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-4

Though `composer install` command worked well, I could not manage to create a new project since I encountered the following error regarding GIT.

Any solution ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PHP on command line uses a different php.ini file, go to ./path/to/your/php/php.ini and manually uncomment the SSL extension to activate it for CLI.

Answer (score 0):

There was a scheduled maintenance period of github within the last 12 hours if my memory serves correctly. I saw something about it on twitter. You might want to try again and see if that was it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some days ago. I fixed it installing git again (from http://git-scm.com/downloads) selecting "Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt" in the "Adjusting your PATH enviroment" window setup. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, your PATH variable was edited and the path to git was removed.  I am assuming this because you somehow already had Laravel cached when installing the new project.

Modify your path variable to include the git bin directory.  Mine is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` and try running the command again.  Ensure each path is separated with a `;`.

I was able to install laravel using that same exact command appropriately.  I then removed the git directory from my path variable, and tried the same composer command and got the exact same error.  (Laravel is cached and could not clone doctrine/lexer).